# Do we want topic challenges here on Pets?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

### [Completed](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge)

A great suggestion from Jon Ericson is to have [Weekly Topic Challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work), these would involve 4 steps:

**Step 1:** Ask for topic ideas.

**Step 2:** Post a challenge.

**Step 3:** Profit!!!! Tally the results.

**Step 4:** Repeat until no more topics are left.

For the full details, follow the link above.

What do people think of this idea?  Do we want this on Pets.se?

If so, should we start as a biweekly challenge, like we are working on [over on **Sustainable Living** beta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/biweekly-topic-challenge-suggest-a-topic-now), or will we get enough attention to do 1 per week, like we're doing [on **Gardening & Landscaping** beta](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge)?

Comment: I see you are leading the efforts at 'Sustainable Living' and 
'Gardening & Landscaping' are you interested in leading the efforts here as well, or just putting this out there for someone else to take up?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I'm also doing it on Earth science. I think I'll kick it off unless I get a willing volunteer (which would be more than welcome).

Comment: Looks like Matt S. [Volunteered](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1949), congratulations to you both, Matt for taking the lead and J. Musser for passing it on.

Comment: Yes, thanks Matt S., I was a little swamped. :P @James np, I hope it works out for you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I lean towards biweekly, posting as separate answer so that it can be voted.  No objections to trying weekly.

Answer (score 1):

My vote is yes. I also think we could be active enough to do a weekly challenge, but if that's too much work, I guess we could do biweekly.