# Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge

Tags: discussion, challenge

It seems to me like we're okay to start biweekly topic challenges here at Pets. The idea for these challenges can be found in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work), and the process has been nicely written out over at the [Gardening and Landscaping post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/595/2984).

> 1. Suggest topics in the answers below.
> 2. Next monday, I (or a volunteer) will pick one of the topics and write up a new meta post introducing the challenge for the following
>      week. The topic will be associated with a specific tag (or tag set) so
>      that we can count how many questions were asked. Please use one topic
>      per answer.
> 3. Anyone who wants to participate asks about the topic of the week.
> 4. At the end of the week, the organizer post an answer to the challenge with a count of how many questions were asked and anything
>      else they feel like highlighting (like favorite questions or notable
>      achievements).
> 5. The organizer picks a new topic and starts back on step #2.

This will keep going as long as there are topics suggested in the answers below that match the rules for the challenge. When an accepted topic has run through the time period for the challenge, the answer will be edited and marked as completed and the next highest answer will become the next topic for the challenge.

**Rules:**

1. If the suggestion is for a tag, then it must be for an already existing tag with at least 3 questions using it. The couple times we've tried to create tags using the challenge it hasn't worked out very well.
2. If the suggestion is for a tag, then it must have a wiki attached. That way people who haven't used the tag before will know what it's for. It doesn't need to be perfect, just something to start with.

Suggestions Will be accepted into the challenge once they reach a score of 3 or more. That way I (or anyone else running the challenge) will know that there is at least a small agreement with the suggestion, and that it is potentially a viable topic for the challenge.

Have fun!

Comment: On other sites I've seen challenges that were not necessarily bound to specific tags.  It doesn't have to be tag-based (let alone single-tag-based) if somebody comes up with some other theme.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You're right. I reworded the rules to specify that they apply  only if the suggestion is for a tag.

Answer (score 3):

### [[Cancelled]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/biweekly-topic-challenge-recipes)

[recipes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recipes) I know Matt has posted a couple of answers about reptile food, and "homemade" dog treats are very popular.  There are even recipes for rabbit treats.

Comment: Definitely need to make sure we're clear on the purpose of the recipe tag!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of [status-completed](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) challenges:

### 2015

April 5<sup>th</sup> to April 19<sup>rd</sup>. [junior-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-pets) - 
[Biweekly Topic Challenge: Junior-Pets [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/biweekly-topic-challenge-junior-pets)

March 10<sup>th</sup> to March 23<sup>rd</sup>. [hamsters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamsters) - [Biweekly Topic Challenge: Hamsters [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/biweekly-topic-challenge-hamsters)

February 23<sup>rd</sup> to March 8<sup>th</sup>. [habitat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitat) - [Biweekly Topic Challenge: Habitat [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/biweekly-topic-challenge-habitat-complete)

February 9<sup>th</sup> to February 23<sup>rd</sup>. [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) - [Biweekly Topic Challenge: Training [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/biweekly-topic-challenge-training-completed)

January 26<sup>th</sup> to February 9<sup>th</sup>. [first-aid](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-aid) - [Biweekly Topic Challenge: First-Aid [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/biweekly-topic-challenge-first-aid-completed)

January 12<sup>th</sup> to January 26<sup>th</sup>. [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) - [Biweekly Topic Challenge: Senior-Pet [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/biweekly-topic-challenge-senior-pet)

---

### 2014

December 22<sup>nd</sup> to January 5<sup>th</sup>: [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation) - [Biweekly topic challenge: Mental-Stimulation [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/biweekly-topic-challenge-mental-stimulation-completed)

December 8<sup>th</sup> to December 22<sup>nd</sup>: [molting](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molting) - [Biweekly topic challenge: Molting [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/biweekly-topic-challenge-molting-completed)

November 24<sup>th</sup> to December 8<sup>th</sup>: [rescue-organizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rescue-organizations) - [Biweekly topic challenge: Rescue Organizations [Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/biweekly-topic-challenge-rescue-organizations-completed)

Answer (score 3):

### [[Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/biweekly-topic-challenge-junior-pet)

We've had senior pets, but what about the [junior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-pet) scenario, specifically around raising young animals such as kittens, puppies, etc.

Comment: [tag:junior-pets], plural.

Answer (score 2):

### [[Completed]](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/biweekly-topic-challenge-hamsters)

[hamsters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamsters) are one of primary first mammal pets for children in the US, and probably other areas as well.  Currently we only have 7 question about them, surely they are worthy of much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to tackle a really big topic, I think it would be really cool to build up some of the basic care questions and answers.

If you have an animal you're interested in, you could ask a question about what you would need in order to care for that animal.

Or, if you want to share what you know about your pet, you could do that too.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that our next topic challenge be the combination of two tags [dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog) & [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) there are [currently 107 questions in this group](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs+training).  But it feels like there is a lack of general questions, teaching sit, stay, and other basic training that most life long dog parents take for granted.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see a biweekly challenge on [amphibians](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amphibians). All sorts of questions could be asked about frogs, toads, salamanders, axolotls, newts, tadpoles and more.

Answer (score 0):

Let's build up some of the [exotic-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exotic-pets) questions. I think having more questions on, for example, spiders, snakes, amphibians, insects, geckos and other reptiles would drive a bunch more traffic to our site from search engines when people look for answers to those questions.

It's not limited to only owners of those types of pets, either. Anyone curious could ask the questions. I actually think it would be great to see questions from some of our non-exotic-pets-owners about exotic pets.

Comment: This also helps follow the ideas I set out in [this answer](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-we-promote-our-site/680#680) to this [How do we promote our site?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-we-promote-our-site) question.

Comment: This answer would be better if was less general.  Pick one animal that you think is under represented but which there strong potential for growth and post that as an answer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins We do have an [exotic-pets] tag. But all right, I'll think about it and add a single-animal suggestion later.

Comment: Did you get an idea for a single animal or species?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Do you think [amphibians] is still too broad?

Comment: I think that is much better, give it a shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

[homemade-toys](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homemade-toys) as an offshoot of [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation) the idea for homemade toys comes to mind as a good topic, though I admit I am not sure how we can frame good questions on the topic.  If anyone has ideas please edit this answer, to give a couple of good examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stake a spot in the answer suggestion queue here with [marking](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marking); a tag that is all about where and how and why a pet claims territory in that way that they do.  Two questions overlap with [territory](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/territory).