# Biweekly topic challenge: Rescue Organizations [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1949/) is [the suggestion for rescue organizations](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1991).

For the next two weeks (until December 8, 2014) you are challenged to ask or answer as many questions as you can using the [rescue-organizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rescue-organizations) tag.

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 21 questions about [rescue-organizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rescue-organizations).

The total voting score the questions received was 97 for an average voting score of 4.6 per question.

There were 32 answers for an average of 1.5 answers per question.

The questions asked were:

- [Are there any animal charities that focus on preventing pets from being rehomed in the first place?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/are-there-any-animal-charities-that-focus-on-preventing-pets-from-being-rehomed)
- [I noticed many rescues do not offer same day adoptions, Why not?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6932/i-noticed-many-rescues-do-not-offer-same-day-adoptions-why-not)
- [Are all animal shelters run by rescue organizations?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/are-all-animal-shelters-run-by-rescue-organizations)
- [Am I allowed to take existing pets to the shelter to meet potential pets?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/am-i-allowed-to-take-existing-pets-to-the-shelter-to-meet-potential-pets)
- [What sort of questions will the rescue centre ask me to ensure I am ready to adopt?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/what-sort-of-questions-will-the-rescue-centre-ask-me-to-ensure-i-am-ready-to-ado)
- [How long can I spend with an animal to get to know it before adopting?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6922/how-long-can-i-spend-with-an-animal-to-get-to-know-it-before-adopting)
- [Why is it that many rescues charge more for adoptions than I could get a puppy for from a breeder?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6917/why-is-it-that-many-rescues-charge-more-for-adoptions-than-i-could-get-a-puppy-f)
- [How should I respond to questions about current vet when filling out an application for a rescue if I do not currently have any pets?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6909/how-should-i-respond-to-questions-about-current-vet-when-filling-out-an-applicat)
- [Are shelter pets rejects?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/are-shelter-pets-rejects)
- [Can you buy your way to the head of the list to get a pet into a restricted access shelter?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6874/can-you-buy-your-way-to-the-head-of-the-list-to-get-a-pet-into-a-restricted-acce)
- [Are there rescue organisations for reptiles?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6858/are-there-rescue-organisations-for-reptiles)
- [After getting a pet from an animal shelter, should I take it to the vet for a checkup?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/after-getting-a-pet-from-an-animal-shelter-should-i-take-it-to-the-vet-for-a-ch)
- [Do rescue animals get vaccinated?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/do-rescue-animals-get-vaccinated)
- [How much time should I expect to volunteer at a shelter in order to be useful?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/how-much-time-should-i-expect-to-volunteer-at-a-shelter-in-order-to-be-useful)
- [Other than cash (always welcome), what donations might be of the greatest use for rescue organizations?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/other-than-cash-always-welcome-what-donations-might-be-of-the-greatest-use-fo)
- [What types of volunteer activites are often associated with animal rescues?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6844/what-types-of-volunteer-activites-are-often-associated-with-animal-rescues)
- [Why does this rescue group want to talk to my vet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6843/why-does-this-rescue-group-want-to-talk-to-my-vet)
- [What are my options for re-homing my pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/what-are-my-options-for-re-homing-my-pet)
- [How accurate are personality descriptions given by a rescue organization?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6836/how-accurate-are-personality-descriptions-given-by-a-rescue-organization)
- [What are the expectations of pet fosters?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/what-are-the-expectations-of-pet-fosters)
- [Is getting pure breed pets from a rescue an option?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-getting-pure-breed-pets-from-a-rescue-an-option)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for starsplusplus at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for critters at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for monica-cellio at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for john-cavan at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for monica-cellio at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for mhwombatat at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for johnny at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for skippy-le-grand-gourou at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for medica at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for jalynn2 at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for matt-s at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for critters at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [rescue-organizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rescue-organizations) tag were:
[adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption)[shelter](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shelter)[introducing-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introducing-pets)[dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs)[cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats)[veterinarian](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veterinarian)[behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)[reptiles](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reptiles)[diseases](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diseases)[vaccination](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vaccination)[equipment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment)[pet-selection](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-selection)[fostering](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fostering)[purebred](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purebred)