# Biweekly topic challenge: Molting [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1949/) is [the suggestion for the molting tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1991).

For the next two weeks (until December 22, 2014) you are challenged to ask or answer as many questions as you can using the [molting](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molting) tag.

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Comment: Honestly I'm having a hard time thinking of mammal questions for molt. Should we expand it to include shed?

Comment: @Zaralynda The challenge is designed to give focus, if molt leads you to questions to ask on shedding go for it.

Comment: Man, it is tough to find obscure molt topics, but I've got a couple.

Comment: This tag really should be renamed to "molting" for consistency, but I won't rename it during this challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 3 questions about [molting](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molting).

The total voting score the questions received was 13 for an average voting score of 4.33 per question.

There were 2 answers for an average of 0.66 answers per question.

The questions asked were:

- [What is the difference between shedding and molting in Rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/what-is-the-difference-between-shedding-and-molting-in-rabbits)
- [Can I help a pet snake through the molting process?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7023/can-i-help-a-pet-snake-through-the-molting-process)
- [Is it safe to feed my pet lizard a molting cricket?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7031/is-it-safe-to-feed-my-pet-lizard-a-molting-cricket)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for joshdm at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for derrick-k at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [molting](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molting) tag were:
[rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits)[terminology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)[shedding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shedding)[snakes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snakes)[feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding)[crickets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crickets)