# Biweekly topic challenge: Mental-Stimulation [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1949/) is [the suggestion for the Mental-Stimulation tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1991).

For the next two weeks (until January 5, 2015) you are challenged to ask or answer as many questions as you can using the [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation) tag.

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 2 questions about [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation).

The total voting score the questions received was 4 for an average voting score of 2 per question.

There were 3 answers for an average of 1.5 answers per question.

The questions asked were:

- [What kind of toys are appropriate for a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/what-kind-of-toys-are-appropriate-for-a-rabbit)
- [Any serious studies of pets and music?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/any-serious-studies-of-pets-and-music)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for keshlam at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for hussein-shehady at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for iheartbunnies at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for chimp at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation) tag were:
[rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits)[communication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication)