# Biweekly Topic Challenge: Senior-Pet [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1949/) is [the suggestion for the Senior-Pet tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1991).

For the next two weeks (until January 26, 2015) you are challenged to ask or answer as many questions as you can using the [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) tag.

**The tag wiki:**

> Specific needs of our senior companions and ways to improve their
>   overall well-being and health.

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Comment: Just so everyone knows, this is not about "senor-pets", aka male chihuahuas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 6 questions about [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet).

The total voting score the questions received was 15 for an average voting score of 2.5 per question.

There were 9 answers for an average of 1.5 answers per question.

The questions asked were:

- [Can an elderly cat adjust to a new cat in the household?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/can-an-elderly-cat-adjust-to-a-new-cat-in-the-household)
- [How common is hyperthyroidism in older cats, and is there anything that can be done to reduce the odds?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/how-common-is-hyperthyroidism-in-older-cats-and-is-there-anything-that-can-be-d)
- [Elderly cat with cancer no longer using litterbox to defecate - options](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/elderly-cat-with-cancer-no-longer-using-litterbox-to-defecate-options)
- [What is the cause of splayed/spread front legs in an older rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/what-is-the-cause-of-splayed-spread-front-legs-in-an-older-rabbit)
- [How can I help an older cat with arthritis?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/how-can-i-help-an-older-cat-with-arthritis)
- [What are the risks to metacam with a cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7319/what-are-the-risks-to-metacam-with-a-cat)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for kate-paulk at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for monica-cellio at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for kate-paulk at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for oldcat at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for john-cavan at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for darthnesscoveredthesky at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for mhwombat at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) tag were:
[multi-pet-families](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-pet-families)[cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats)[health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health)[toilet-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training)[rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits)[medicines](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicines)