# Biweekly Topic Challenge: First-Aid [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) is [the suggestion for the First-Aid tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1977).

For the next two weeks (until February 9, 2015) you are challenged to ask or answer as many questions as you can using the [first-aid](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-aid) tag.

**The tag wiki:**

> Refers to a situation requiring application of initial treatment in
>   case of an accident such as how to stop profuse bleeding. Not for
>   real-time questions.
>
> First-aid is the initial treatment received in case of an accident.
>   This tag will be used for situations regarding application of first
>   aid, such as how to stop profuse bleeding. This tag is not for
>   real-time questions requiring real-time answers. Do not expect
>   immediate answers.

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 6 questions about [first-aid](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-aid).

The total voting score the questions received was 19 for an average voting score of 2.7 per question.

There were 6 answers for an average of 1 answer per question.

The questions asked were:

- [What is the appropriate first aid for a cat nosebleed?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7420/what-is-the-appropriate-first-aid-for-a-cat-nosebleed)
- [Why is my rat drooling and opening its mouth? Is it choking?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7447/why-is-my-rat-drooling-and-opening-its-mouth-is-it-choking)
- [What should I do if I catch my cat eating a poisonous plant?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/what-should-i-do-if-i-catch-my-cat-eating-a-poisonous-plant)
- [My rats had a fight and one of them is injured - what can I do for him?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7517/my-rats-had-a-fight-and-one-of-them-is-injured-what-can-i-do-for-him)
- [What should be in a leopard gecko first aid kit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/what-should-be-in-a-leopard-gecko-first-aid-kit)
- [My leopard gecko's tail fell off! What should I do?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7529/my-leopard-geckos-tail-fell-off-what-should-i-do)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for piper at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for matt-s at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for starsplusplus at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for darthnesscoveredthesky at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for piper at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for john-cavan at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for keshlam at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [first-aid](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-aid) tag were:
[cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats)[upper-respiratory-disease](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upper-respiratory-disease)[rat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rat)[poison](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poison)[injury](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury)[reptiles](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reptiles)[lizards](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lizards)[leopard-geckos](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leopard-geckos)[autotomy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autotomy)

Comment: Ha. I guess my [question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-antiseptic-is-safe-to-use-on-reptiles) and [answer](http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/7563/628) were out of time?

Comment: @starsplusplus Yeah, so far I've been counting Mondays as the start of new challenges.

Comment: Shame - I read "until 9 February" as inclusive, and you hadn't posted this when I wrote the question (though the answer took me a while, and you'd written this before I was through).