# Biweekly Topic Challenge: Training [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) is [the suggestion for the training tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1980).

For the next two weeks (until midnight of February 22, 2015) you are challenged to ask and/or answer as many questions as you can using the [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag.

**The tag wiki:**

> Training includes correcting problematic behavior and teaching a pet new behavior or habits.
>
> This tag can indicate behavior-changing tricks and tips applied either in the home setting, or by a professional training program.  Related tags include [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior), [discipline](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline), [leash-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leash-training) and [toilet-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training).

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Comment: Is trust training included? I'm thinking possibly not, since I think the focus is more on tricks etc, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: @Piper I didn't see anything in the suggestion that would limit it to anything. As long as it makes sense for the question to use the tag I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 6 questions about [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) (with 1 duplicate question omitted).

The total voting score the questions received was 20 for an average voting score of 3.3 per question.

There were 8 answers for an average of 1.3 answer per question.

The questions asked were:

- [Trained dog to ring bell to go out, now he rings it all the time](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/trained-dog-to-ring-bell-to-go-out-now-he-rings-it-all-the-time)
- [How can I train my dog to fetch (or at least not bark for me to throw the ball)?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7588/how-can-i-train-my-dog-to-fetch-or-at-least-not-bark-for-me-to-throw-the-ball)
- [My dog licking up other dogs urine?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7637/my-dog-licking-up-other-dogs-urine)
- [My cat thinks my cursor arrow is a toy but my expensive LED monitor disagrees!](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7664/my-cat-thinks-my-cursor-arrow-is-a-toy-but-my-expensive-led-monitor-disagrees)
- [In giving my cat a "space" (bed) on my desk, should I strictly enforce that she stay there only?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/in-giving-my-cat-a-space-bed-on-my-desk-should-i-strictly-enforce-that-she)
- [Can I use an aversive to keep my cat from licking my plate?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/can-i-use-an-aversive-to-keep-my-cat-from-licking-my-plate)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for fluffysheap at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for veg at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for crystal at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for curiouswebdeveloper at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for dalton at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for layna at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for jeffaudio at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for mario at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for mark-vedder at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for keshlam at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag were:
[dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs)[toilet-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training)[vocalizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocalizations)[fetch](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fetch)[cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats)