# Biweekly Topic Challenge: Habitat [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) is [the suggestion for the habitat tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1952).

For the next two weeks (until midnight of March 8, 2015) you are challenged to ask and/or answer as many questions as you can using the [habitat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitat) tag.

Unfortunately the tag has no wiki at the moment, so I guess bonus points to whomever creates it?

Essentially this tag is used for questions involving an animals living space. Typically terrariums and aquariums.

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Comment: Really?  "Habitat" seems a little redundant with "Terrarium" and "Aquarium".

Comment: Thread to revise / eliminate Habitat tag: http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/habitat-redundant-synonym-tag-or-eliminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no posts that used this tag for the time period.

Comment: In fact, it may have been removed from a few.