# Biweekly Topic Challenge: Hamsters [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) is [the suggestion for the hamsters tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1965).

For the next two weeks (until midnight of March 22, 2015) you are challenged to ask and/or answer as many questions as you can using the [hamsters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamsters) tag.

The tag has no wiki attached.

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Comment: Too bad we don't have a banner location to advertise these.

Comment: Remember kids:it's hamsters, not hampsters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the two weeks of the challenge we received 2 questions about [hamsters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamsters)

The total voting score the questions received was 4 for an average voting score of 2 per question.

There were 2 answers for an average of 1 answer per question.

The questions asked were:

- [Can a hamster be litter box trained?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/can-a-hamster-be-litter-box-trained)
- [Why is my hamster awake all night?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/why-is-my-hamster-awake-all-night)

These questions were asked by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for james-jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

And answered by these users (in no specific order):

[image: profile for piper at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

[image: profile for tlp at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Tags that were used in conjunction with the [hamsters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamsters) tag were:
[behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)[toilet-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training)