# Biweekly Topic Challenge: Junior-Pets [Completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) is [the suggestion for the junior-pet tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1999).

For the next two weeks (until midnight of April 19, 2015) you are challenged to ask and/or answer as many questions as you can using the [junior-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-pets) tag.

The tag has no wiki attached.

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

First off, didn't we have this discussion?  It's [junior-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-pets), not "junior-pet" (fixed).  Pluralization!

Second, this tag doesn't even have any questions that exist with it.  I almost think it is a disservice to generate questions for a nonexistent tag, but I went ahead and re-tagged several puppy/kitten/egg questions with [junior-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-pets), which may or may-not end up being relevant.  Also created the tag wiki.

Your move, Pets.SE community.

Comment: I don't see why this is a necessary tag what so ever.

Comment: With the lack of action of others during this challenge, I agree.