# Why do we have a junior-pets tag? What does it mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

So I noticed we apparently now have a "junior-pets" tag. It feels very much like a strange meta tag to me, and I am not sure why we have it, as it isn't something anyone would really search for, as it doesn't seem to be a very common term at all.

What service does this tag provide?

Comment: Appears to have driven topic management for a challenge. In that context, I think it's okay, but it could be removed (or possibly renamed) now that the challenge is over.

Answer (score 1):

It apparently is the polar opposite of the [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) tag.

It was proposed during the [Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) by moderator John Cavan, and became a high-voted answer (upvoted to 3 at this time), defined loosely as:

> We've had senior pets, but what about the junior-pet scenario, specifically around raising young animals such as kittens, puppies, etc.

During the actual work time of [The Junior-Pets Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/biweekly-topic-challenge-junior-pets-completed), I was the only participant to put the new tag "out there", doing so reluctantly:

> this tag doesn't even have any questions that exist with it. I almost think it is a disservice to generate questions for a nonexistent tag, but I went ahead and re-tagged several puppy/kitten/egg questions with junior-pets, which may or may-not end up being relevant. Also created the tag wiki.

I created the tag wiki to oppose [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) as follows:

> Addresses specific needs of younger / newborn pet companions, and ways to improve their overall well-being and health.

And stated `Your move, Pets.SE community.`, leaving it up to others to determine whether or not we should continue with the process.  No one decided to tag any other questions; I chalked that up to the same lack of participation I've seen during the other challenges, as I had left the discussion floor open in my answer to the challenge.

Obviously it rubs you the wrong way.  You're welcome to revert those tag appliques (just make sure you leave any functional changes that might have been made, because I tend to multi-task in my edits).

Comment: Well, to be honest, I proposed a topic, not a tag. I realize that the appearance of a tag is in the answer, but it wasn't specifically to cause that to happen. In any event, I'm certainly not wedded to it existing as a tag if there's no real value in it.

Comment: That was probably my mistake then. I guess I misinterpreted the suggestion as being for a new tag when I made the post for the challenge.