# Biweekly Topic Challenge: Recipes [Cancelled]

Tags: discussion, challenge

The current topic for the [Pets: Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/pets-biweekly-topic-challenge) is [the suggestion for the recipes tag](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1975).

For the next two weeks (until midnight of May 3, 2015) you are challenged to ask and/or answer as many questions as you can using the [recipes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recipes) tag.

*There is no wiki attached to this tag.*

---

At the end of the challenge the results will be tallied into an answer below this post. Have fun!

Comment: There is nothing in this tag that I can see, and no wiki for it. What sort of things are you expecting, here?

Comment: @AshleyNunn I have no idea. I'm just taking the highest voted suggestions from the list.

Comment: ... What kind of recipes? Medicinal ones? Weight-boosting ones? Any and all? I'm confused.

Comment: I think the core Challenge thread needs to be re-proposed, with guidelines to use existing tags, and to not allow any tag to be proposed if it doesn't have a tag wiki established and at least 2-3 questions solidly tagged.

Comment: I've appended a set of rules on the topic challenge post. If anyone disagrees with them, let me know. @JoshDM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this challenge should be cancelled because there are no pre-existing questions on the tag.

Comment: Or maybe all the challenges should be canceled for lack of participation?  It started out good, but not sure it is still adding value.

Comment: @JamesJenkins We could hiate it for a while and come back to it, perhaps? I'm not sure the suggestions themselves are strong enough at present. The shelter suggestion got a lot of upvotes, but the second or third one had just one upvote IIRC. Perhaps with a break people might be able to come up with stronger ideas. I'm not sure if we've got enough active people on meta at the moment...